# MariaDB - Indexing not improving performance on char(255) field

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, mariadb, database-performance

I'm trying to execute this SQL query on a table which has a little shy of 1 million records:

```
SELECT * FROM enty_score limit 100;
```

It gives me result in about 600 ms

As soon as I add a where clause on a field  `` `dim_agg_strategy` char(255) DEFAULT NULL ``, it takes 40 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM enty_score WHERE dim_agg_strategy='COMPOSITE_AVERAGE_LAKE' limit 100;
```

I've tried to create an index but there is no improvement it still takes 40 seconds to execute the same query:

```
ALTER TABLE `enty_score` ADD INDEX `dim_agg_strategy_index` (`dim_agg_strategy`);

SELECT INDEX_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CARDINALITY, NULLABLE, INDEX_TYPE 
FROM information_schema.statistics where INDEX_NAME = 'dim_agg_strategy_index';


INDEX_NAME            |COLUMN_NAME     |CARDINALITY|NULLABLE|INDEX_TYPE|
----------------------+----------------+-----------+--------+----------+
dim_agg_strategy_index|dim_agg_strategy|        586|YES     |BTREE     |
```

A little more info, this column which I have placed in where clause just contains 6 distinct values:

```
select distinct dim_agg_strategy from enty_score;

dim_agg_strategy         |
-------------------------+
COMPOSITE_AVERAGE        |
COMPOSITE_AVERAGE_ALL    |
COMPOSITE_AVERAGE_LAKE   |
COMPOSITE_AVERAGE_NONLAKE|
NORMALISED_AVERAGE       |
SIMPLE_AVERAGE           |
```

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer noticed that there were very few different values for that indexed column.  So it realized that a lot of the rows would be needed.  So it decided to simply plow through the table and not bother with the index.  (Using the index would involve bouncing back and forth between the index's BTree and the data's BTree a lot.)

So, you counter by pointing out the `LIMIT 100`.  This is a valid question.  Alas, this points out a deficiency in the Optimizer.

It is torn between

- Ignore the index, which is likely to be optimal if it needed to scan the entire table.  Note:  That would happen if the 100 rows you needed happened to be at the end of the table.
- Use the index, but pay the extra overhead.  Here it is failing to realize that 100 is a lot less than 1M, hence improving the odds that the index would usually be the best approach.

Let's try to fool it...  DROP that index and add another index.  This time put 2 columns:

```
 (dim_agg_strategy, xx)
```

where `xx` is some other column.

(Let me know if this trick works for you.)